# Retrieving HTML form data in POST http header in Python

Tags: python, html, http

I have the following HTML code. It creates a form and once i hit submit, POST a request to the server.

```
 <html>
 <body bgcolor = black text= white>
 <FORM method="post" action="/processData.py">
 <P>
 <LABEL for="firstname">First name: </LABEL>
 <INPUT type="text" id="firstname"><BR>

 <LABEL for="lastname">Last name: </LABEL>
 <INPUT type="text" id="lastname"><BR>

 <LABEL for="email">email: </LABEL>
 <INPUT type="text" id="email"><BR>

 <INPUT type="radio" name="sex" value="Male"> Male<BR>
 <INPUT type="radio" name="sex" value="Female"> Female<BR>

 <INPUT type="submit" value="Send"> <INPUT type="reset">
 </P>
 </FORM>
 </body>
 </html>
```

When i hit submit i get a POST http request on my web server. But instead of getting the values for all the fields. I am getting only the radio button value. Here is the header i am getting:

```
POST /Test.html HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:22222
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8) AppleWebKit/536.25 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0 Safari/536.25
Content-Length: 10
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*//*;q=0.8
Origin: http://127.0.0.1:22222
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Referer: http://127.0.0.1:22222/File.html
Accept-Language: en-us
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive

sex=Female
```

I was expecting the data to show up after the header. why is it not showing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you need to define `name` attributes for all inputs

right now only the radio's have names

```
<INPUT type="radio" name="sex" value="Male"> Male<BR>
<INPUT type="radio" name="sex" value="Female"> Female<BR>
```

give name attribute:

```
<LABEL for="lastname">Last name: </LABEL>
<INPUT type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname"><BR>
```